# How to show custom users in the user table wordpress admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to restrict wordpress custom role to view only specific users in user list.

I have created custom roles (sales). A sales role can view only specific role in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the capability to the sales role by using the following logic,

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    // gets the author role
    $role = get_role( 'sales' );

    // This only works, because it accesses the class instance.
    // would allow the author to edit others' posts for current theme only
    $role->add_cap( 'list_users' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

Comment: You need to create custom capability for custom role. I suggest you to use : https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-roles-and-capabilities/ plugin